# Xcode 8 and ui automation

Tags: xcode, automation, instruments

So, it looks like UI Automation is deprecated in Xcode 8 Instruments.  Is there a way to use the same javascript tests we had with Xcode 7 instruments UI Automation, in Xcode 8 (via command line for automated testing)?

Answer (score 2):

If the App's source code was upgraded to Swift 3, then we have to rewrite the scripts in Swift 3 using XCUI or we have to look at alternative automation tools such as Appium(supports Java Scripts).

As long as the code and its dependencies are still in Swift 2.3 or earlier, we can set Command Line Tools(from XCode preferences) to XCode 7.3.X and use the same old command to run the Tests.